# "JSONException: End of input at character 0 of" on getting data

Tags: java, android, json, request

I'm trying to get JSON Data from a API from Reviewmeta
The request gives back the following:

```
{
"rating":"3.9",
"s_overall":"3",
"href":"https:\/\/reviewmeta.com\/amazon\/SOMETEXTHERE",
"count":"1198"
}
```

when I'm trying to get out the **count** value I only get this error:

> 03-27 20:46:27.580 18567-18567/at.mrminemeet.reviewcheck E/JSON EXEPTION: ERROR: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

I'm using this to get the JSON information with an ASYNC Task:

```
public class ReviewMetaDATA extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressDialog.setMessage("Daten anfordern");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                ReviewMetaDATA.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL reviewmeta_url= new URL(url[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) reviewmeta_url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        Log.d("Info", result.toString());
        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String str) {

        try {

            JSONObject jresult = new JSONObject(str);

            int count = jresult.getInt("count");

            Log.d("REQUEST", String.valueOf(count));


            this.progressDialog.dismiss();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON EXEPTION", "ERROR: " + e.toString());
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in the try-catch in the **onPostExecute** funktion as the lines befor that try will be executed.
I also checked some other posts talking about this but I did't figure out that much.

Any ideas to fix that or what I did wrong?

Comment: `End of input at character 0` means that `str` is empty. Maybe if you **stop** catching and **ignoring exceptions**, you'd find out why it fails. *Hint:* `e.printStackTrace();` is ignoring the exception, because you allow program flow to continue as-if nothing went wrong. Perhaps you should `Log.e` instead of printing.

Comment: What does  Log.d("Info", result.toString()); output to you?

Comment: Your `result` returning blank from `doInBackground()` . Debug your code and try to find out Why? Also perform all parsing stuff inside `doInBackground()` and return an Result Object(POJO) to `onPostExceute()`.

Comment: There is quite a bit wrong with your code, eg. you do not check the response code in order to see if `HttpURLConnection` was successful, you do not check the return string with your JSON data to see if it is empty--do not rely on try...catch to correct errors in your logic. And a simple one--why not just dismiss the progress dialog when you enter the `onPostExecute` method (making sure it isn't `null` of course)?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque somehow it puts nothing

Comment: it looks like your request didn't work then, probably something happened and was caught in e.printStackTrace();

Comment: check it out and let us know what you find out

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque I tried some things and it seems that it jumps out of the try at the `InputStream in = new ...`
 I think the `urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) reviewmeta_url.openConnection();` doesn't get a connection.
How can I check that to be shure?

Comment: checkout the answer, you forgot to call connect() in your URLConnection object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be getting an empty string as the json response, it might be caused by this:

```
URL reviewmeta_url= new URL(url[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) reviewmeta_url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

You forgot to call `connect()` in your connection, then you end up catching the exception and that's why you get an empty string. Try this:

```
URL reviewmeta_url= new URL(url[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) reviewmeta_url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect(); <<forgot this
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I added the line to it but after that line still it won't do anything.
The _result_ is still empty

Comment: what about your stack trace? e.printStackTrace()?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got the answer.
I found the most embarrasing problem myself and some others problems that caused problems were found by you.

So my biggest fault was, that I somehow managed to delete the Internet permission.
Next problem was that I didn't have the **.connect();** so thanks @Levi Albuquerque

And thanks to @Barns for the hints to make it better.

So here is the working code:

```
public class ReviewMetaDATA extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progressDialog.setMessage("Daten anfordern");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    ReviewMetaDATA.this.cancel(true);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                URL reviewmeta_url = new URL(url[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) reviewmeta_url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR: " + e.toString());
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            Log.d("Info", result.toString());
            return result.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String str) {

            this.progressDialog.dismiss();

            // When str is not empty then do that code
            if(str != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jresult = new JSONObject(str);

                    Log.d("REQUEST", jresult.getString("count"));


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON EXEPTION", "ERROR: " + e.toString());
                }

            }
            // else log it
            else{
                Log.e("Request", "String was empty");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for you help.

And I'm sorry that I bothered you with it.